# I am stuck with a message popup in UPS software

Tags: ups

I have bought a UPS. This came with a mini CD containing software for both Linux and Windows.

You can find it [here](https://energenie.com/service.aspx?item=8735&key=&op=drivers#item) (Energenie: EG-UPS-PS2000-01):

I have installed all related softwares, namely [Nut](https://networkupstools.org), [Observium](https://www.observium.org), and many others.

I succeeded in displaying some info from the UPS in Nut. But the software displays a lot of other info and it does that graphically as well it alerts for errors.

`UPSsmartII64.bin` (ver. 1.2.3.1405) is working except it's asking for a "CD-KEY" every few minutes. This popup window is simply annoying.
CD-key was not provided either in the package, CD or online. Nowhere. You can check this on the online manual that is provided.

I have contacted the company. Company said Linux-based sales are very small (they even provided me with percentages) for a big company to deal with such problems.

However, they communicated with the Chinese software engineers. They didn't provide me with any practical solution to the problem.

They said to install the newest version of `upssmart` which is "`Linux_upsSmartView` V1.0.2" (!!!) from  [here](https://www.idbkmonitor.com/). This does not work either, on Debian 12 or Debian 13 (testing). Some problems with QT5 libraries.

So, my question now is there any app or way to get rid of this popup in linux?

The company seems unable to solve my problem.

Comment: It seems to me that it's up to Energenie to supply the UPSmart-II key. It's their product.

Answer (score 3):

[Nut](https://networkupstools.org) works, so you say.

That means you don't need anything else.
Everything else provided on the CD is just extra fluff.

Nut provides the basic framework to communicate to the UPS.

You can use multiple utilities (command-line or GUI based) to manage/monitor the UPS as long as they use NUT for the underlying communication.
There are many avaialbel and a lot are open source.

You are not limited to the tools provided by the vendor.